# ForceClose on .getString?

Tags: android, eclipse, string

I am trying to pull in a string from one activity to another but every time I try to open the one activity I get a forceclose on `.getString`.

**Logcat Error**

```
10-26 10:36:45.444: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15112):     at http.www.hotapp.com.timeandlocation.email.EmailSettings.onCreate(ThisActivity.java:29)
```

**Activity Calling the string**

```
public class ThisActivity extends Activity{

private TextView reciever;
private String rec;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.elayout);

    reciever = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.Reciver);
    rec = 
        getIntent()
        .getExtras()
        .getString
        ("send");
    reciever.setText(rec);

}
```

**Activity with the string**

```
public class OtherActivity extends Activity{
private EditText sendto;
private Button save;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.emailactivity);

    sendto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sendto);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Save);

    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent (EmailActivity.this,EmailSettings.class);
            intent.putExtra("send", sendto.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `getIntent().getStringExtra("send");`

If you want to check if the extra is there use:

```
getIntent().hasExtra("send");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null)
    {
        rec = extras.getString("send");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this by eliminating NULL EXCEPTION from getString() function